# Ubuntu mount -t command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I use following command to mount "/dev/sdb1" to "/storage" directory:
mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /storage

After run above command, I can use "df -h" can see it:
/dev/sdb1             147G  188M  140G   1% /storage

But after i restart the server, it disappear, and i have to run mount command again.

Is there a command that can keep the mount even if i restart the server?

Comment: Belongs on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your [/etc/fstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) file:

```
#    device name    mount point    fs-type    options    dump-freq    pass-num
     /dev/sdb1    /storage       ext3       defaults    0            0
```

You can run (as root):

```
echo "/dev/sdb1    /storage    ext3    defaults    0    0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add relevant information to [`/etc/fstab`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab).